# How do I inflate a spinner from an array parsed with GSON

Tags: android, spinner, gson, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to the GSON library, I have a json data structure that looks like this.

{"networks":[{"networkId":0,"networkName":"Friends"},{"networkId":"1","networkName":"something"},{"networkId":"4","networkName":"a second thing"},{"networkId":"28","networkName":"another network"},{"networkId":"2","networkName":"blah"}]

I get this data through the following request

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();

client.setDebug();
client.AddParam("method", "get_user_networks");
client.AddParam("session_key", sessionKey);

client.Execute();

String response = client.getResponse();

NetworksData retval = null;
Gson gson = new Gson();
retval = gson.fromJson(response, NetworksData.class);
```

the Networks data class looks like this

```
public class NetworksData {

private List<Network> networks;
private List<Group> groups;

public List<Network> getNetworks() {
    return this.networks;
}

public List<Group> getGroups() {
    return this.groups;
}

public void setNetworks(List<Network> networks) {
    this.networks = networks;
}

public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}
```

}

and the invididual network class is the following

```
public class Network {

private String networkName;
private Integer networkId;

public String getName(){
    return this.networkName;
}
public Integer getId(){
    return this.networkId;
}
public void setName(String nameIn){
    this.networkName = nameIn;
}
public void setId(Integer idIn){
    this.networkId = idIn;
}
```

}

I'm trying to inflate a spinner with the network names, I can manually traverse the array and build a String array and inflate it that way, but that seems counter intuitive to the whole object model. Isn't there a way to get the list directly into the spinner?

Here is a way that works but is wrong

```
networkItems = new String[total];


// networks
if (retval.getNetworks().size() > 0) {

    for (Network network : retval.getNetworks()) {
    networkItems[i] = network.getName();
    i++;

       }
}
```

and then inflate the spinner like so

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, networkItems);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        networkSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your custom Adapter using your nerworks list or NetworksData object. You can subclass [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) to implement the Adapter (note that you can also subclass or compose with ArrayAdapter (or any other implementation) to reuse it).